# Формат строки. Не соответствует инициализации. В чем проблема?

Tags: c#, winforms

Данные в ручную заполняются в dataGridView1.
По нажатию button184_Click, должен выполнятся запрос (запись данных из dataGridView1) и все это дело должно попадать в файл базы данных .mdf.
В место этого... проблема... Как её можно локализовать?
1 таблица 
7 столбцов

p.s. проверьте пожалуйста... у меня тут все правильно?

```
   private void button184_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var ConnStr = "Connection";

try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
        {
            comm.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var strQuery = "INSERT INTO Поезд (№_вываывфаыв,твыип_пввыаа,паывт_отвыавыаения,пуыавывакт_прыыва,ство_ввыпвов,коапия,певапь_кввапя)" + 
                           "VALUES (@№ ппвапа,@тпвапп повапа,@пват оапапвапия,@папт прапия,@копватво ввапнов,@ковапния,@певапиаость вапвания)";
                comm.CommandText = strQuery;
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@№ пвапда", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@тпвап папа", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@пвапвакт овапия", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@пвапт праптия", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@квапво ввапнов", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@коапя", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@переапть капапия", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                // больше параметров ...
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    throw;
}


            }
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хаха, ох уж эта хенд мейд обфускация =) Простите, не удержался.

Comment: Попробуйте `throw new SqlException();`. И в `catch` блоке смените тип исключения на `SqlException`.

Comment: Лучше бы вы в базе хранимые процедуры заранее создали, а потом просто из кода их вызывали передавая нужные параметры, чем городить эти ужасные `пвапвакт овапия`. Прежде чем пихать какой-то SQL запрос в код C# работу этого запроса нужно оттестировать на базе с помощью SQL Server Management Studio, потом создать на его основе хранимую процедуру и будучи полностью уверенным в ее работоспособности уже вставлять вызов в код.

Comment: Хотя бы показали у вас поля в таблице, а то как проверить может у не совпадают типы данных? Например, sql ожидает int, а вы ему string подпихиваете

Comment: @Alexsandr Ter спасибо я исправил нашел ошибки